# Sort complex vectors in specific order

Tags: matlab, sorting, complex-numbers, eigenvalue

I have vector with eigenvalues:

```
e = 

-0.4094 + 3.9387i
-0.4094 - 3.9387i
-0.0156 + 0.5645i
-0.0156 - 0.5645i
```

And I would like to sort this vector like that:

e_sort =

```
-0.0156 + 0.5645i
-0.4094 + 3.9387i
-0.0156 - 0.5645i
-0.4094 - 3.9387i
```

The rule is:
First must be:

```
 -a+b*i
```

and then:

```
 -a-b*i
```

We can say, that:

```
  0 < b_1 < b_2 < ... < b_n
```

Thanks,

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Yeah, I tried function sort and stuff like that, but nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
e1 = e(imag(e) >= 0);
e2 = e(imag(e) < 0);
newe = cat(1,sort(e1),sort(e2))

newe =

-0.0156 + 0.5645i
-0.4094 + 3.9387i
-0.0156 - 0.5645i
-0.4094 - 3.9387i
```